# Routing example.com to www.example.com for secure https connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-certificate-manager

I have an AWS loadbalancer with a certificate routed from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) that works fine using HTTPS. On a desktop-top browser example.com will automatically route to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). On a phone example.com doesn't add the www and loses its HTTPS secure connection. Is there a way to fix it? The URL on the certificate is formatted like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can setup AWS load balancer to redirect HTTP to HTTPS by adding listeners:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

Alternatively, you could make these redirects happen as it hits the application server (using IIS for example):

Http => Https
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.ssl.com/how-to/redirect-http-to-https-with-windows-iis-10/amp/

Non www to www
https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www

Comment: Ty for the answer. So http://www.example.com does route to https://www.example.com. Without the www neither htttp or https will connect.

Comment: Edited answer to show non www as well

Comment: This ended up working fine. When I requested the certificate I needed to add a second domain for the www version. They both get routed to the load balancer and the http version redirects to the https. Thanks